# An open set containing the boundary of another open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $W$ is a bounded open set of $\mathbb{R}^m$ ($m>1$) such that  $\mathbb{R}^m\setminus W$ is connected. If $V$ is an open set having its boundary $\partial V$ in $W$, can we conclude that $V\subset W$?

Comment: Sorry!I corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $W=\{x\in\Bbb R^m\,:\, \lVert x\rVert<1\}$ and $V=\{x\in\Bbb R^m\,:\, \lVert x\rVert>1/2\}$.